# How to allow Steam to write into root directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, root, steam

I've just installed the latest Linux Mint version and I'm trying to set up some Steam games. I only have 10 GB on my home directory, so I'm willing to create a game library inside the root directory (`/usr/games/steamlibrary`). I was able to create a folder there, but I have no idea how to let Steam write there. I get the following error: 'New Steam library folder must be writeable'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead to think about *how make Steam able to write to...* you should think about *how make that folder writeable to me*;
probably you will get the same result but it has a different logic and mostly affect security: I would not be happy if an application can easily write in my root!

---

Anyway, I would make writable the folder to me:

```
chown -hR $USER:$GROUP /usr/games/steamlibrary
```

where *$USER* is your user and *$GROUP* your group.

In this way you are able to write to that dir (even if it resides in the root), thus to Steam.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow steam to write outside of your home partition.

What you should really do is to resize your home partition. The simplest way to do it is to boot linux from a thumbdrive and use gparted to resize the home partition.

[An article that explains how to do it on ubuntu](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd)

If you still want to save your steam games to your root partition, you need to let steam write to `/usr/games/steamlibrary`. To do that, you need to change the directory's permission using `sudo chmod +rw` this command makes it so that you can read and write as the current user without using `sudo`.

You really should resize your home partition though.

Comment: Did you conversely meant to say `You shouldn't allow steam to write outside of your home partition.`